# 3gbps / 6gbps / 12gbps HDD - does interface speed really matter?

Tags: hard-drive

Currently there are no mechanical hard drives (non-ssd/sshd) that can max out or even get close to 3gbps data transfer, what's the point of having drives with 6 or even 12gbps interface speed?

Answer (score 3):

Traditional HDDs come pretty close to 3 Gbit/s - e.g. Seagate Exos peaks at 270 MB/s. SSDs can easily saturate 6G and should run on 12G or PCIe. Hybrids are somewhere in between, severely hampered when hooked up to 3G.

Additionally when used a SAS expander (switch), often the expander doesn't support changing the interface speed in between host adapter and drive - therefore, putting a 3G drive in an otherwise 12G stack eats up valuable host adapter time when talking to the 3G drive. Potentially, the whole stack could be permanently downgraded to 3G when there's a mix.

Comment: So, what is the point have mechanical (non-SSD, non-SSHD) with 12Gbit/s?

Answer (score 3):

Think about this in terms of the electronics, SAS interfaces and components.

Flip your question around: 
If 12Gbps is the current standard and **it's backward compatible with previous versions**, why would you continue to manufacture 6Gbps and 3Gbps parts?

Server manufacturers are installing 12Gbps backplanes. Manufacturing and economies of scale within that process point to using the most compatible solution.

Comment: And why pay extra for something with absolutely no benefit in any form?

Comment: @vanowm I don't think you understand.

Comment: Your answer is more about interface on "receivers" than HDD itself. It makes sense have a higher speed interface on controllers/backplates, where new faster HDD can be upgraded later, but you can't upgraded the HDD itself, now can you?